# How to override WebKit's PDFViewSavePDFToDownloadFolder?

Tags: cocoa, macos, webkit

I have an application that includes a WebView, which automatically displays PDFs in WebKits WebPDFView. When the user hovers above the lower portion of the document, an overlay appears that enables zooming, opening in Finder and saving the PDF in the download folder.

I would like to implement the latter, but I have no idea how to go about it, except that I need to implement PDFViewSavePDFToDownloadFolder. However, where do I implement it? I'd appreciate any pointers.

Comment: When I searched Google for that word, it came up as already implemented by WebPDFView. So I'm curious what told you you need to implement it somewhere yourself.

Comment: The implementation in WebPDFView won't do you any good. I'm one of the developers for Vienna (vienna-rss.org). Clicking on that corresponding symbol in our app does exactly nothing.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to monkey patch Apple's built-in PDF viewer, you can't unless you want to use a code injection hack that is guaranteed to break. If you want to implement your own PDF viewer, then you build a WebKit plugin.

Comment: I have come to the same conclusion over the day... Seems I'll just leave this as is - non-working.